# Tilde Error in Formula

Tags: formula

I'm trying to create a formula field that will return a tilde symbol (~) if the referrencing field is blank.

So I'm using the blank value field and I'm getting the following message.

BLANKVALUE( fHCM2__Home_Address_2__c, ~)

**Error: Syntax error. Found '~'**

How can I get this formula to work properly and return a ~ if the field I'm referencing is blank?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

Surround the tilde in either single or double quotes. "Smart" quotes (i.e. `“ ”` or `‘ ’`) will not work

Strings and single characters need to be enclosed in quotes. Otherwise the formula tries to interpret it as something that's part of the "formula"'s own language (like `+`, which either adds numbers or concatenates strings).

The problem with that is that formulas don't use `~` for any operator. It's not part of the "language" of formulas, hence it's a syntax error if it is encountered (outside of a quoted string).